# Why is not Edittext in Android vertically centered relative to its outside box?

Tags: android-edittext

[image]Say, a default EditText is created. It has a default padding around the white editbox.
The default padding at the bottom is larger than the padding on the top. 
This means: the center horizontal line of the EditText is not at the center of the white editbox.

If I put a imageView, Align Right and Center Vertical with the EditText, the imageview is not at the center of the white editbox.

I could manually nudge it. But I am afraid it will not apply to all devices.
A better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow this tutorial, this will achieve what you want and look great at the same time.  http://www.wapolabs.com/2012/10/17/android-tip-1-customizing-an-edittext-view/

It is not good practice to put an anything in an edit text but text. Stick with customizing the edit text view as its not hard and keeps good functionality.

and as always set the padding when you customize an edit text to force the text to the exact spot you want it. padding will look fine on all phones.

Comment: Thanks. Personally I do not want to make it more complicated. My current solution is to manually add some padding to nudge it to the vertical center.

Comment: That solution is fine. The padding won't look different on any phone. So in that case you are fine.